# Upper bound for variance of kernel averages

Tags: statistics, asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds, mixing

I'm reading [Hansen's (2008, p. 729)  Theorem 1](https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/%7Ebhansen/papers/et_08.pdf) where he bounds the variance of averages of the form
$$\hat\Psi(x)=\frac1{Th}\sum\limits_{t=1}^T Y_t K\bigg(\frac{x-X_t}h\bigg)$$
given that $\{(Y_t,X_t)\}_{t=1}^T$ is a colection of random variables and $K$ is a kernel function. Under some conditions he obtained
$$Var(\hat \Psi)\leq \frac C{Th}$$

In the framework I'm working on, $X_t=\frac tT$ and thus deterministic. Does it change the rate of convergence (that is, the above upper bound)?

It is important to mention that he is working with mixing sequences (not independent cases). He make assumptions on the boundedness of conditional expectation $\sup_x E(Y_t\mid X_t=x)$ and the density $f$ of $X_t$. But in my case, it doesn't make any sense at all.

Can someone give me suggestions to tackle this problem?

**Comment**

I already obtained a bound  $\frac C{Th^2}$ (discarding assumptions involving the density of $X_t$). In the asymptotic framework $h\to 0, Th^2\to \infty$ as $T\to\infty$ it means the bound I obtained converges slowly than Hansen's.
For the experienced people, is this expected or I can improve this result?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmm. Have you looked at the proof of Theorem 1? Something is wrong there. Specifically, on page 739 he writes $nh^d\operatorname{Var}(\hat{\Psi})\le (...)h^d\equiv\Theta h^d$.

Comment: @d.k.o. Yes. I studied this theorem but did not see anything wrong. I will check your note.

Comment: @d.k.o. Thanks for pointing this. I proved this differently from him. Although I believe his inequality is not incorrect since it is assumed $n$ large enough so that $h^{-d}\geq j^*$ where $j^*$ is some natural number /index (in page 738). This means $1\geq 1/j^*\geq h^d$. So $(\dotsc)h^d\leq \Theta$. I believe the index starts at $1$, if not, just increase $n$ so that $h^d\leq 1$. We can do this since $h\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the underlying model is $Y_t=m(X_t)+\epsilon_t$, where $\epsilon_1,\ldots,\epsilon_T$ are i.i.d. $(0,\sigma^2)$. Also let $Z_t:=K((X_t-x)/h)$.  Then

$$
\hat{\Psi}(x)=\frac{1}{Th}\sum_{t=1}^T  m(X_t)Z_t+\frac{1}{Th}\sum_{t=1}^T\epsilon_t Z_t .
$$
Since $X_t$'s are not random,
$$
\operatorname{Var}(\hat{\Psi}(x))=\frac{\sigma^2}{(Th)^2}\sum_{t=1}^T Z_t^2=\frac{\sigma^2}{Th}\times\mathsf{E}\frac{1}{h}K^2\!\left(\frac{u_T-x}{h}\right),
$$
where $u_T= \lceil Tu\rceil/T$ and $u\sim U[0,1]$. Further analysis depends on the properties of the kernel function. For example, when $K$ is the Gaussian kernel and $x\in (0,1)$,
$$
\mathsf{E}\frac{1}{h}K^2\!\left(\frac{u_T-x}{h}\right)\to \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The case when the errors are $i.i.d$ is straightforward (to me). In my case, the errors are weakly dependent ($\alpha$-mixing). I believe that for $X_t=t/T$ does not change the results of Hansen. I can think $X_t=t/T$ as $i.i.d$ draws from $U[0,1]$. Then I can apply the results of Hansen directly for my case. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Yes. Assuming that each $X_t$ is an independent draw from $U[0,1]$ would simplify the analysis.

Comment: Sure. I was trying to do the calculations for the very particular case $X_t=t/T$. Unfortunately, I lack the vision of a statistician and didn't realize this.

Comment: Please, take a look on this question, where I referred you https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4460577/fixed-and-random-design-equivalence-in-nonparametric-regression